# Lag rows in list

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to lag by a factor of 2 rows or 1 row some columns in my dataframe. I do this so that every row aligns properly.[image: Here an extract from my dataframe.] I can easily do it with a single dataframe as follows (lag Column 1 by two rows, columns 2,3,4 and 6 by one row, and remove rows that become empty `filter(V1 != '')` ).

However I want to do this for a list of 50 dataframes. How can I build a function that does what is below? Any suggestion?

Thank you!

```
  DF <- DF %>%
  mutate(V1=lag(V1, n=2)) %>%
  mutate(V2=lag(V2)) %>%
  mutate(V3=lag(V3)) %>%
  mutate(V4=lag(V4)) %>%
  mutate(V6=lag(V6)) %>%
  filter(V1 != '') %>%
  na.omit()
```

Comment: Please share sample data reproducibly instead of in a picture.

Comment: What is the command to extract data on R?

Comment: `dput()` makes copy/pasteable versions of data, e.g., `dput(your_data[1:5, ])` for the first 5 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `lapply`: Here is an example with three of your presented dataframe in a list:

```
# Create 3 df with same content
df1 <- test
df2 <- test
df3 <- test

# make a list
my_list <- list(df1, df2, df3)

# the function remove na.omit and use select_if(~ !all(is.na(.))) to remove column V5
my_function <- function(df) {
    
    df %>%
        mutate(V1=lag(V1, n=2)) %>%
        mutate(V2=lag(V2)) %>%
        mutate(V3=lag(V3)) %>%
        mutate(V4=lag(V4)) %>%
        mutate(V6=lag(V6)) %>%
        filter(V1 != '') %>%
        select_if(~ !all(is.na(.)))
}

# apply the function to the list of dataframes
lapply(my_list, my_function)
```

Output:

```
> lapply(my_list, my_function)
[[1]]
# A tibble: 8 x 9
     V1 V2                    V3            V4          V6            V7    V8 v9      V10  
  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>       <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1    31 CABANE BOLIBE         BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BOLIBE         1     1 510 100 A    
2    32 INSTITUT LONGONYA     BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BOGBAMBASO     1     2 510 101 A-B  
3    33 INSTITUTMONZEMBE      BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BUNDUKI        1     3 510 102 A    
4    34 CABANE BALISANGU      AVURU-DUMA    BALISANGO   DEMELI         1     2 510 103 A-B  
5    35 EP. TAMBALA           AVURU-DUMA    DENGWA      ANGBAPIO I     1     2 510 104 A-   
6    36 EP. DENGWA            AVURU-DUMA    DENGWA      GUNDU          1     2 510 105 A-B  
7    37 EP. NAMBWA            AVURU-DUMA    GBUTA       AVAY           1     2 510 106 A-   
8    38 CABANE de BONGBONDOLO MOBATI-BOYELE BANGBONDOLA BOKUSI         2     2 510 107 A-B  

[[2]]
# A tibble: 8 x 9
     V1 V2                    V3            V4          V6            V7    V8 v9      V10  
  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>       <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1    31 CABANE BOLIBE         BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BOLIBE         1     1 510 100 A    
2    32 INSTITUT LONGONYA     BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BOGBAMBASO     1     2 510 101 A-B  
3    33 INSTITUTMONZEMBE      BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BUNDUKI        1     3 510 102 A    
4    34 CABANE BALISANGU      AVURU-DUMA    BALISANGO   DEMELI         1     2 510 103 A-B  
5    35 EP. TAMBALA           AVURU-DUMA    DENGWA      ANGBAPIO I     1     2 510 104 A-   
6    36 EP. DENGWA            AVURU-DUMA    DENGWA      GUNDU          1     2 510 105 A-B  
7    37 EP. NAMBWA            AVURU-DUMA    GBUTA       AVAY           1     2 510 106 A-   
8    38 CABANE de BONGBONDOLO MOBATI-BOYELE BANGBONDOLA BOKUSI         2     2 510 107 A-B  

[[3]]
# A tibble: 8 x 9
     V1 V2                    V3            V4          V6            V7    V8 v9      V10  
  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>         <chr>       <chr>      <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <chr>
1    31 CABANE BOLIBE         BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BOLIBE         1     1 510 100 A    
2    32 INSTITUT LONGONYA     BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BOGBAMBASO     1     2 510 101 A-B  
3    33 INSTITUTMONZEMBE      BONDONGOLA    BOZAGE      BUNDUKI        1     3 510 102 A    
4    34 CABANE BALISANGU      AVURU-DUMA    BALISANGO   DEMELI         1     2 510 103 A-B  
5    35 EP. TAMBALA           AVURU-DUMA    DENGWA      ANGBAPIO I     1     2 510 104 A-   
6    36 EP. DENGWA            AVURU-DUMA    DENGWA      GUNDU          1     2 510 105 A-B  
7    37 EP. NAMBWA            AVURU-DUMA    GBUTA       AVAY           1     2 510 106 A-   
8    38 CABANE de BONGBONDOLO MOBATI-BOYELE BANGBONDOLA BOKUSI         2     2 510 107 A-B
```

data:

```
test <- structure(list(V1 = c(31, NA, NA, 32, NA, NA, 33, NA, NA, 34, 
NA, NA, 35, NA, NA, 36, NA, NA, 37, NA, NA, 38, NA, NA), V2 = c(NA, 
"CABANE BOLIBE", NA, NA, "INSTITUT LONGONYA", NA, NA, "INSTITUTMONZEMBE", 
NA, NA, "CABANE BALISANGU", NA, NA, "EP. TAMBALA", NA, NA, "EP. DENGWA", 
NA, NA, "EP. NAMBWA", NA, NA, "CABANE de BONGBONDOLO", NA), V3 = c(NA, 
"BONDONGOLA", NA, NA, "BONDONGOLA", NA, NA, "BONDONGOLA", NA, 
NA, "AVURU-DUMA", NA, NA, "AVURU-DUMA", NA, NA, "AVURU-DUMA", 
NA, NA, "AVURU-DUMA", NA, NA, "MOBATI-BOYELE", NA), V4 = c(NA, 
"BOZAGE", NA, NA, "BOZAGE", NA, NA, "BOZAGE", NA, NA, "BALISANGO", 
NA, NA, "DENGWA", NA, NA, "DENGWA", NA, NA, "GBUTA", NA, NA, 
"BANGBONDOLA", NA), v5 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
V6 = c(NA, "BOLIBE", NA, NA, "BOGBAMBASO", NA, NA, "BUNDUKI", 
NA, NA, "DEMELI", NA, NA, "ANGBAPIO I", NA, NA, "GUNDU", 
NA, NA, "AVAY", NA, NA, "BOKUSI", NA), V7 = c(NA, NA, 1, 
NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, NA, 
NA, 1, NA, NA, 2), V8 = c(NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 3, 
NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2, NA, NA, 2), v9 = c(NA, 
NA, "510 100", NA, NA, "510 101", NA, NA, "510 102", NA, 
NA, "510 103", NA, NA, "510 104", NA, NA, "510 105", NA, 
NA, "510 106", NA, NA, "510 107"), V10 = c(NA, NA, "A", NA, 
NA, "A-B", NA, NA, "A", NA, NA, "A-B", NA, NA, "A-", NA, 
NA, "A-B", NA, NA, "A-", NA, NA, "A-B")), class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -24L), spec = structure(list(
cols = list(V1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), V2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), V3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), V4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), v5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_logical", 
"collector")), V6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), V7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), V8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), v9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), V10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), skip = 1L), class = "col_spec"))
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of lagging you could use a grouping/collapsing approach like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

# some sampe data
df <- data.frame(col1 = c(31,NA,NA,32,NA,NA,33),
                 col2 = c(NA,2,NA,NA,2,NA,NA),
                 col3 = c(NA, NA, 3, NA, NA, 3, NA))
df
  col1 col2 col3
1   31   NA   NA
2   NA    2   NA
3   NA   NA    3
4   32   NA   NA
5   NA    2   NA
6   NA   NA    3
7   33   NA   NA

df %>%
    # fill itenfiying column downwars
    tidyr::fill(col1, .direction = "down") %>%
    # change all nas to empty character
    dplyr::mutate(across(everything(), ~ifelse(is.na(.x), "", .x))) %>%
    # group by the identifier
    dplyr::group_by(col1) %>%
    # collapse everything acording to identifier
    dplyr::summarise(across(everything(), ~paste0(.x, collapse = ""))) %>%
    # always ungroup grouped data to avoid unwanted behaviour down stream
    dplyr::ungroup() 

# A tibble: 3 x 3
   col1 col2  col3 
  <dbl> <chr> <chr>
1    31 "2"   "3"  
2    32 "2"   "3"  
3    33 ""    ""
```

You will have to convert the columns to your desired data types though

Answer (score 1):

Since you did not provide data, I am guessing you want to repeat the process of fixing the rows for several data frames. You can use the following function:

```
fixmydata <- function (DF){
  DF <- DF %>%
  mutate(V1=lag(V1, n=2)) %>%
  mutate(V2=lag(V2)) %>%
  mutate(V3=lag(V3)) %>%
  mutate(V4=lag(V4)) %>%
  mutate(V6=lag(V6)) %>%
  filter(V1 != '') %>%
  na.omit()
return(DF)
}
```

#In the main script use the following lines

```
#create a name list of the dfs
names_df <- c("DF1", "DF2",...)

#use for loop with get to call all the data frames

for(i in names_df){
DF <- get(i)
fixed_DF <- fixmydata(DF)
#finally assign it to the respective data frame
assign('i', fixed_DF)
}
```

With the limited information provided, this should help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood you correctly, using lapply on the list of dataframes (`df_list`) should do what you want.

```
DF_function <- function(data){

clean_data <- data %>%
  mutate(V1=lag(V1, n=2)) %>%
  mutate(V2=lag(V2)) %>%
  mutate(V3=lag(V3)) %>%
  mutate(V4=lag(V4)) %>%
  mutate(V6=lag(V6)) %>%
  filter(V1 != '') %>%
  na.omit()

return(clean_data)

}

lapply(df_list, DF_function)
```